# Console.log to Document.write

Tags: javascript, php, json

show console.log file in main display. document.write is making problem

this is the url data

```
[{"call_time":"0","total_inc_traffic":"1363.10","total_out_traffic":"88.70"},{"call_time":"1","total_inc_traffic":"479.57","total_out_traffic":"36.98"},{"call_time":"2","total_inc_traffic":"239.57","total_out_traffic":"13.43"},{"call_time":"3","total_inc_traffic":"190.28","total_out_traffic":"8.20"},{"call_time":"4","total_inc_traffic":"223.80","total_out_traffic":"0.00"},{"call_time":"5","total_inc_traffic":"158.87","total_out_traffic":"19.58"}]
```

this is script code:

```
<script>
    var ourRequest =new XMLHttpRequest();
    ourRequest.open('GET','http://localhost/icx/test/link.html');
    ourRequest.onload = function(){
      var ourData = JSON.parse(ourRequest.responseText);

    let result = ourData.map(v => Number(v.call_time));
    console.log(result);

    };
    ourRequest.send();

</script>
```

How to display the result in main display? Not in the Console

Comment: what do you mean by `main display`?

Comment: my console output is (15) [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]    i want to show in the main page...such as if I write Document.write instead of console.log then the page keeps reloading.So what should i do?

Comment: I expained it just now. I dont now how to express more. Sorry but I am a new coder

Comment: no class or ID just what to print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] from the url

Comment: You can use `document.write` for testing purposes, but this will clear the full of your existing code. Otherwise get a HTML element from JS, and set its content by `.innerHTML`

Comment: To display JS objects like in console, You can `JSON.stringify()` the values before writing. Note that this will remove some value types.

Comment: @TanvirNabil  i am agreed with FZs comments